# How to copy files from 1 folder to another where folders names are dynamic using shell script

Tags: shell, dynamic, copy, names

I am trying to copy files which are in different folder. Folders name change dynamically during run time. So i tried to save it in a variable and tried to copy . Its throwing error. Could u please help me to resolve

```
current_path : '/tmp/build/bf45481f'
brokerutils='/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/*'
broker='/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/AuthServiceBroker_New/'

path_source="$current_path$brokerutils"
path_dest="$current_path$broker"

cp -R "${path_source}${path_dest}"

Path_dest:/tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/AuthServiceBroker_New/
```

> Path_source:/tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/BrokerRoutes.js
>   /tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/DALAdapter.js
>   /tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/gistdb.js
>   /tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/middleLayer
>
> Error : cp: missing destination file operand after
>   '/tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/BrokerCommonUtils/*/tmp/build/bf45481f/resource-app/ServiceBrokers/AuthServiceBroker_New/'

Answer (score 1):

***Simple Example for copying files from 1 folder to another where folders names are dynamic using shell script***

```
!/bin/bash  
echo "Enter sourc path:"  
read sourc  
echo "Enter dest path:"  
read dest  
path_source="$sourc"  
path_dest="$dest"  
cp -rf $path_source $path_dest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is at less one error : you miss a space between ${path_source} and ${path_dest}.
Try with `cp -R "${path_source} ${path_dest}"`

Comment: I tried 

cp -rf $path_source $path_dest

Its working now... Thanks for the response